# Error 0x80070002 while installing Nokia device recovery tool

Tags: windows-7

I tried installing Recovery tool on windows 7 as well as on 10 but am getting the same error.

[image]

The log file is [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/92od44vd9tzbsog/Nokia_Software_Recovery_Tool_6.0.3_20160630170826.log).
Please help me asap!
I am trying to reflash the os to my Nokia 503

Comment: You should ask this in Super User. This site is not associated with Microsoft nor Nokia. **This a QA site about Windows Phone and phone only.** Nokia 503 is not a Windows Phone. As far as this site is concerned your question is off-topic. Ask it in Super User SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this questions is not about Windows phone. This question can be asked on Super User instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently the latest version of this tool is 6.2.55 (as of writing this answer).

[image: Nokia Software Recovery Tool Installer]

Older versions won't install because the installer tries to download payloads that Microsoft has removed from their servers. Download the latest version and install that one.

The official download link (Microsoft) for the latest version is always: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525568

Comment: here is the package that this installation software tries to download without success [0BF0:1414][2016-12-03T14:03:04]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to acquire payload from: 'http://download-fds.webapps.microsoft.com/supportFiles/phones/files/recovery/Drivers/USBSerialPortDriver/1.1.8.1526/USBSerialPortDriver.msi'

Comment: Thanks. this worked for me. +1